# Randomly grab three locations by slicing an array based off of comparison of location

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, random

I have an array and I am grabbing 3 random locations out of it. The third location cannot be a restaurant. This will make sense when you see the code.

What I would like to do is make sure each location is at least 1 mile away from the previous location.

CODE:
Here is my existing code. Currently it grabs three locations but they could be really close to each other.

```
for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
}
let third = a[0];
let [first, second] = a.filter(l => !l.restaurant).slice(1);
let selectedLocations = [first, second, third];

function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

            let Rm = 3961;
            let Rk = 6373

            lat1 = deg2rad(lat1);
            lon1 = deg2rad(lon1);
            lat2 = deg2rad(lat2);
            lon2 = deg2rad(lon2);

            let dlat = lat2 - lat1;
            let dlon = lon2 - lon1;

            let a  = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat/2),2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlon/2),2);
            let c  = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(1-a)); // great circle distance in radians
            let dm = c * Rm; // great circle distance in miles
            let dk = c * Rk; // great circle distance in km

            let mi = round(dm);
            let km = round(dk);
            let ft = Math.round(mi * 5280.0);

            return mi
}

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        let rad = deg * Math.PI/180; // radians = degrees * pi/180
        return rad;
    }

    function round(x) {
        return Math.round( x * 100) / 100;
    }
```

Remember the (**third**) location is grabbed first. Once I have the third location I would like to go through the array until I find another location at least 1 mile away from the third location.

This new location will become the (**second**) location and then once I have that location (**second**) I need to go through the array again and find one at least 1 mile away from it. This will be the final (**first**) location.

UPDATE:
Here is something along the lines of what I am talking about but I know there has to be a cleaner way of writing it

```
            for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
            }
            // We get our third location.
            let third = a[0];
            console.log(third)

            // Build a new array removing the third location and 
            // any other locations that is a restaurant
            let newarray = a.filter(l => !l.restaurant).slice(1);


            // filter our new array based on the location being at 
            // least 1 mile away from the third location
            let second = newarray.filter(function (e) {
                return calculateDistance(
                            third.geolocation.lat, 
                            third.geolocation.lng, 
                            e.geolocation.lat, 
                            e.geolocation.lng
                        ) >= 1
            })

            // We now have our second location
            console.log(second[0]);


            // build a new array removing the second location
            let thirdarray = second.slice(1);

            // filter our new array based on the location being at 
            // least 1 mile away from the second location
            let first = thirdarray.filter(function (e) {
                return calculateDistance(
                            second[0].geolocation.lat, 
                            second[0].geolocation.lng, 
                            e.geolocation.lat, 
                            e.geolocation.lng
                        ) >= 1
            })

            // we now have our first location
            console.log(first[0]);
```

Comment: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @StackSlave I’m not sure what you are proposing? My code is above. Within that code I need to add the comparing aspect

Comment: It would help greatly if you were to include some sample data with your question. Also, how are you handling cases where there are not three locations at least a mile apart? Can location 1 and location 3 be within a mile of each other, so long as they're both a mile away from location 2?

Comment: @fubar I am ok with locations 1 and 3 being close. I just need the distance between 1 and 2 and the distance between 2 and 3 to be at least 1 mile.

Comment: @fubar I updated my question to show an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I am sure there is a better way to write it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link I posted in comments, I've included a tiny library to accommodate your needs:

```js
//<![CDATA[
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, mobile, M, I, S, Q, rad, distance, withinOneMile, sortCityDists; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || this;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = (url, send, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(typeof FormData !== 'undefined' && send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      let s, r = [];
      for(let p in send){
        s = send[p];
        if(typeof s === 'object')s = JSON.stringify(s);
        r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+encodeURIComponent(s));
      }
      x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); x.send(r.join('&'));
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  const w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  const w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
rad = n=>n*Math.PI/180;
distance = (latLng, toLatLng)=>{
  let ll = latLng, lL = toLatLng;
  if(ll instanceof Array){
    ll = {lat:ll[0], lng:ll[1]};
  }
  if(lL instanceof Array){
    lL = {lat:lL[0], lng:lL[1]};
  }
  const lng1 = ll.lng === undefined ? +ll.lon : +ll.lng;
  const lng2 = lL.lng === undefined ? +lL.lon : +lL.lng;
  const m = 6371e3, lat1 = +ll.lat, lat2 = +lL.lat, lat1R = rad(lat1);
  const lat2R = rad(lat2), latD = rad(lat2-lat1), lngD = rad(lng2-lng1);
  const n = Math.pow(Math.sin(latD/2), 2)+Math.cos(lat1R)*Math.cos(lat2R)*Math.pow(Math.sin(lngD/2), 2);
  return m*2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(n), Math.sqrt(1-n));
}
withinOneMile = (latLng, toLatLng)=>{
  if(distance(latLng, toLatLng)*3.2808/5280 <= 1){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
sortCityDists = (citiesArrayOfObjs, originIndex = 0)=>{
  const cities = citiesArrayOfObjs.slice(), baseLatLng = cities.splice(originIndex, 1)[0].latLng, dists = [];
  cities.forEach(o=>{
    dists.push({city:o.city, meters:distance(baseLatLng, o.latLng)});
  });
  dists.sort((a, b)=>a.meters-b.meters);
  return dists;
}
// you can put the below on another page - besides the end load and beyond
const cities = [{city:'Seattle', latLng:[47.6038321, -122.3300624]}, {city:'New York', latLng:[40.7127281, -74.0060152]}, {city:'Chicago', latLng:[41.8755616, -87.6244212]}, {city:'San Francisco', latLng:[37.7790262, -122.4199061]}];
const meterDists = sortCityDists(cities).reverse(), mileDists = [];
console.log(meterDists);
meterDists.forEach(o=>{
  mileDists.push({city:o.city, miles:o.meters*3.2808/5280});
});
console.log(mileDists);
const locs = [[47.6038321, -122.3300624], [47.6038321, -122.3500624], [47.6038321, -122.3800624]], res = [];
for(let i=0,n=1,loc1,loc2,l=locs.length; n<l; i++,n++){
  loc1 = locs[i]; loc2 = locs[n];
  if(withinOneMile(loc1, loc2)){
    res.push(loc1, loc2);
  }
  else{
    break;
  }
}
console.log(res);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

As you can see, you pass an Array of Objects to `sortCityDists` and the result is an Array of Objects in order by distance from least to greatest, based on the first Element of the passed Array. Format can be seen by looking at the  `cities` Array of Objects. Just `.reverse()` to flip the Array around.

Comment: Thx StackSlave but unfortunately this does not solve my issue. My code works. It grabs 3 random locations. I just need to add a new variable to it. I need each location to be at least 1 mile apart

Comment: It's as easy as `yourArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*yourArray.length)]` to get a random Array element. So, that shouldn't be so hard. Use my `distance` function to calculate distance. You can pass in two Arrays of `[lat, lng]`, if you want.

Comment: What do you need us for then? I'll update code anyways.

Comment: I am trying to add a new variable into the mix. I want locations 1 and 2 to be at least 1 mile apart and I want locations 2 and 3 to be at least 1 mile apart. I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve that

Comment: To further explain. my code randomly grabs 3 locations. it does this by randomizing the array, grabbing the first object, then filtering the remaining objects to NOT include restaurants and it grabs the next 2 locations.

Comment: After it grabs the first location, I then need to compare that location with all the others in the array and filter out any that are less than 1 mile between. Then take the first object of that newly filter array. Next it needs to compare that second object with the remaining objects and eliminate any that are less than 1 mile between and then grab the first object of that filtered array.

Comment: I updated my question to show an example of what I am trying to accomplish but I feel there is a cleaner way to write it